# what is semantically right to use in case of layer/window of a SPA

Tags: html, single-page-application

Situation: have a module that works with several window/layers that cover 100% screen surface, excluding a navigation, of course. Each of those is just different representation(or different parts) of the same piece of information(object, entity).

What is semantically right to use for the piece of html that represents

- the whole module?
- each window/layer?

E.g.:

```
<section class="module">
    <section class="layer-description">
        ...
    </section>
</section>
```

or:

```
<section class="module">
    <div class="layer-description">
        ...
    </div>
</section>
```

or introduce my set of tags(?):

```
<module>
    <layer>
        ...
    </layer>
</module>
```

Comment: take a look at [this](http://html5doctor.com/avoiding-common-html5-mistakes/). It think it can help you answer your question

Comment: yeah, reading the article right now. with regards to this https://rawgit.com/whatwg/html-differences/master/Overview.html#new-elements i can assume that my second and third solutions are pretty okay...